# In .Net do I need to do double checked locking

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

If I want to lazy instantiate a class that holds a lot of data and I want it to only have one instance (Singleton), then do I need to double check the object before I setup the instance? (.Net). Or is it ok to have only the single check as done in AnotherWayForSingletonInstance

Here is the code:

```
class MyHeavyClass
{
private MyHeavyClass()
{
}

private static object _lock = new object();
private static MyHeavyClass _instance;
public static MyHeavyClass Instance{
    get{
        //check 1
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock(_lock)
            {
                //check 2
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new MyHeavyClass();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}

public static MyHeavyClass AnotherWayForSingletonInstance{
    get{
        lock(_lock)
        {
            //check 1
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new MyHeavyClass();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Will there be alternate threads accessing this singleton, or is this the only thread that runs this code?

Comment: There could be multiple threads accessing the singleton

Comment: Or you could just use the `Lazy<T>` class ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *never* need double-checked locking - it's purely a performance optimization that relies on platform-dependant memory ordering tricks to avoid locking in most cases.  Single-checked locking is always sufficient, more portable, and simpler, so you should prefer it unless benchmarks show you really need that small boost.  But there's an even better solution.

You should avoid explicitly locked singletons entirely.  Instead, try static initializers since they're simple, (thread)safe, fast, and lazily loaded.

```
sealed class MyHeavyClass
{
    MyHeavyClass() {}
    public static readonly MyHeavyClass Instance = new MyHeavyClass();
}
```

**Such instances are not created at application startup**, but somewhat lazily before first the type or field is first used.  The exact rules are [depend on whether a static constructor is present](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx), but if you're ok with the initializer sometimes executing earlier than necessary, this is fine.  On .NET v4, the initialization is [very lazy](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx).  99% of the time this should be your go-to implementation as it's the fastest, simplest one possible.  Even on .NET v3.5 and earlier, this does not load until a method is encountered that refers to the type.

This code can be faster than the lock-based version because once the class is fully loaded, there is no need for guards nor locks in accessing the field.  In particular, the JIT can simply assume the variable is set and could in theory even omit things like null checks and hoist reads out of loops.  If you do need precise control over the timing of the lazy loading; try the simpler lock-then-check rather than double-checked locking (which relies on some tricky memory model details) - but in practice, I suspect almost no-one needs that precise control; you just want to avoid unnecessary work.

With respect to double-checked locking: As far as I know, even on .NET, you need the `volatile` keyword for double-checked locking to be fully portable: ARM implementations of .NET [don't have the same write ordering guarantees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553518.aspx) as you're used to on x86.  Even if it works on ARM and the various mono platforms, **why use such a complex implementation if it's slower than a simple static initializer?**

---

### Benchmark Results

```
  AlwaysLock init
  37.09 nanoseconds per iteration (1000000 iters of AlwaysLock)
  DoubleCheckedLocking init
  2.78 nanoseconds per iteration (1000000 iters of DoubleCheckedLocking)
  StaticInitializer init
  2.13 nanoseconds per iteration (1000000 iters of StaticInitializer)
  StaticConstructor  init
  2.56 nanoseconds per iteration (1000000 iters of StaticConstructor)

  38.45 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 iters of AlwaysLock)
  2.07 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 iters of DoubleCheckedLocking)
  1.57 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 iters of StaticInitializer)
  1.57 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 iters of StaticConstructor)

  21.71 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 sync iters of AlwaysLock)
  4.62 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 sync iters of DoubleCheckedLocking)
  3.15 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 sync iters of StaticInitializer)
  3.17 nanoseconds per iteration (10000000 sync iters of StaticConstructor)
```

### Benchmark Code

```
void Main()
{
    const int loopSize = 10000000;

    Bench(loopSize/10, ()=> AlwaysLock.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize/10, ()=> DoubleCheckedLocking.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize/10, ()=> StaticInitializer.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize/10, ()=> StaticConstructor.Inst);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Bench(loopSize, ()=> AlwaysLock.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize, ()=> DoubleCheckedLocking.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize, ()=> StaticInitializer.Inst);
    Bench(loopSize, ()=> StaticConstructor.Inst);
    Console.WriteLine();
    SBench(loopSize, ()=> AlwaysLock.Inst);
    SBench(loopSize, ()=> DoubleCheckedLocking.Inst);
    SBench(loopSize, ()=> StaticInitializer.Inst);
    SBench(loopSize, ()=> StaticConstructor.Inst);

    //uncommenting the next lines will cause instantiation of 
    //StaticInitializer but not StaticConstructor right before this method.
    //var o = new object[]{ 
    //          StaticInitializer.Inst, StaticConstructor.Inst};
}

static void Bench<T>(int iter, Func<T> func) {
    string name = func().GetType().Name;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.For(0,iter,i=>func());
    var sec = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    Console.Write("{0:f2} nanoseconds per iteration ({1} iters of {2})\n"
        , sec*1000*1000*1000/iter, iter, name);
}

static void SBench<T>(int iter, Func<T> func) {
    string name = func().GetType().Name;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for(int i=0;i<iter;i++) func();
    var sec = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    Console.Write("{0:f2} nanoseconds per iteration ({1} sync iters of {2})\n"
        , sec*1000*1000*1000/iter, iter, name);
}

sealed class StaticInitializer {
    StaticInitializer(){ Console.WriteLine("StaticInitializer init"); }
    public static readonly StaticInitializer Inst = new StaticInitializer();
    //no static constructor, initialization happens before
    //the method  with the first access
}

sealed class StaticConstructor {
    StaticConstructor(){ Console.WriteLine("StaticConstructor  init"); }
    //a static constructor prevents initialization before the first access.
    static StaticConstructor(){}
    public static readonly StaticConstructor Inst = new StaticConstructor();
}

sealed class AlwaysLock {
    AlwaysLock(){ Console.WriteLine("AlwaysLock init"); }
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
    static AlwaysLock _instance;
    public static AlwaysLock Inst { get {
        lock(_lock)
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new AlwaysLock();
        return _instance;
    } }
} 


sealed class DoubleCheckedLocking {
    DoubleCheckedLocking(){ Console.WriteLine("DoubleCheckedLocking init"); }
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
    static DoubleCheckedLocking _instance;

    public static DoubleCheckedLocking Inst { get {
        if (_instance == null)
            lock(_lock)
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new DoubleCheckedLocking();
        return _instance;
    } }
}
```

### TL;DR

Don't use locking for singletons, use static initializers.

Comment: Although, this is a solution for making the instance thread-safe, the instance could be very heavy and may not get used. Hence I dont want to create it unless its required. But I do accept that if I know that the object is going to be always required, creating it using a static initializer is a good solution.

Comment: Eventhough this is good information, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Raj Rao: The static initializer will usually *not* run when it is not used.  It is not run at application startup, but (roughly speaking) on first usage!  So even if you do *not* know that the object is always going to be required, this is still usually the preferred solution.

Comment: @Guffa: I've added a small bit about double checked locking; but the point is it solves the underlying problem he has (namely how to create a singleton), and not the literal question he happens to have posed.  In essence, he asked a question and presupposed one of two answers would be correct, but there's a third solution which is what he's actually after.

Comment: Again, the static initializer has the problem of not being truly lazy (especially if you have other static methods in your class that may never need to use the instance itself). It just seems that adding the double check is a small price to pay in terms of code readability and can pay off a huge amount especially when you are creating an API and have no control on how others may use it). Though I agree, where possible, using a static initializer is the way to go.

Comment: If you're making a singleton, it's not hard to move the offending static methods out of the class (after all, they're static - no need for them to be in the class itself).  Also, if you *avoid* the static constructor, then the lazy initialization does not occur on the first access of any static method but only on the first access of the singleton field.  Basically, if you keep your singletons free from other responsibilities, it should work in all scenarios.

Comment: @Raj Rao: the static initializer can be truly lazy if you avoid certain (rarely problematic) anti-patterns.

Answer (score 1):

A single check works just fine.

The double check is only done for performance reasons. As the lock is only there to prevent multiple threads from creating the instance at the same time, it's only needed when you actually need to create the instance.

Comment: Isnt performance a good reason to use double checking? Or is the performance hit so small, that its better to go for code-readability over performance?

Comment: @RajRao: Yes, performance is a good reason, but it doesn't make the double checking a necessity. If the instance is rarely used, or is used for something time consuming, the double check does very little difference.

Comment: Hi Guffa, check out my answer (there is a comment in there with timing results) and you can see that at sufficiently large number of calls, there is a major gain to be had from a performance perspective. Based on that, I think its probably a good idea to use double checking always, as you never know how many times your Instance method/property may get called.

Comment: @RajRao: Even if you don't know how many times you get an instance, you can know how big part of the whole job getting the instance would be. If your class for example is used for something that takes a millisecond to run, the time for getting the instance is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:
as suggested by @Eamon, the best way to solve threaded access to a static object would be to initialize the static objects using a static initializer (in which case you dont need locks to access the instance) (also, check Eamon's code on how using a static ctor can make it such that the instance is not allocated prior to first access of the class).

But, if you cant use a static initializer, I think it makes sense to use double-checked locking as it can give you a performance boost. From my testing, I found that the performance mattered only when I called the Instance method more than a 100,000 times.

In my code, as well as Eamon's code, at large enough iterations, there was a major performance boost to be had by using double checked locking.

**Here is my test code (runs in LinqPad)**

```
void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        const int loopSize = 10000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < loopSize; i++)
        {
            SingletonSingleLock o = SingletonSingleLock.Instance;
        }

        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();


        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopSize; i++)
        {
            SingletonDoubleLock o = SingletonDoubleLock.Instance;
        }
        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();
    }

    /* Test results
        Elapsed milliseconds
        # of calls to Instance      1,000       10,000      100,000     1,000,000       10,000,000
        SingletonSingleLock             0           0           4           39              433
        SingletonDoubleLock             0           0           1           17              185
    */

    public class SingletonSingleLock
    {
        private SingletonSingleLock()
        {

        }

        private static object _lock = new object();
        private static SingletonSingleLock _instance;
        public static SingletonSingleLock Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock(_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new SingletonSingleLock();
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

    }


    public class SingletonDoubleLock
    {
        private SingletonDoubleLock()
        {

        }

        private static object _lock = new object();
        private static SingletonDoubleLock _instance;

        public static SingletonDoubleLock Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock(_lock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new SingletonDoubleLock();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

    }
```

As can be seen in the screen shot of VS's profiler results, there is a performance gain to be had from double-checked locking.
[image: VS performance results]

Comment: This isn't a good test; it both over and understates the performance advantage of double checked locking.  The point of locking is that it imposes synchronization penalties in a multi-threaded scenario; your test is single-threaded.  Thus the locking penalty is artificially low in your test.  Secondly, you never access a singleton "just because", and the lack of duration between the accesses makes the performance penalty seem more severe than it really is.  Thirdly, since the singleton never changes real code should always save the singleton in a variable and reuse that local reference.

Comment: Hi Eamon Nerbonne, I dont think the locking penalty is artificially low for my double-checked lock, just because I used a single threaded test (accept for the fact that if I tried accessing the instance  many times before it was created. But in normal operation, the access after creation will much greater than before or during creation). After the instance is created, I will never again enter the lock and hence not have to take the hit on locking.

Comment: the double-locking doesn't have the perf cost, it's the single locking which has the perf cost.  In any case, see the benchmark in my ammended answer; the single locking solution is slower in a multithreaded environment.  (But the issue with the unnatural access frequency remains; why access a singleton 10's of millions of times a second?)